# Windows 8 RT App - Passing info between pages

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using SQLite to store data, I have a class:

```
class Customers
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string customerNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string customerName { get; set; }


}
```

How I am sending data is:

```
private void customer_Click(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Customers customer = e.ClickedItem as Customers;

        if(customer != null)
        {
            Customers c = new Customers();
            c.customerName = customer.customerName;
            c.customerNumber = customer.customerNumber;
            c.Id = customer.Id;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(customerDetail), c);
        }
    }
```

I need the data to display in text boxes on the detail page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

From Page:

```
private void customer_Click(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Customers customer = e.ClickedItem as Customers;

        if(customer != null)
        {
            Customers c = new Customers();
            c.customerName = customer.customerName;
            c.customerNumber = customer.customerNumber;
            c.Id = customer.Id;
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(customerDetail), c.Id.ToString());
        }
    }
```

To Page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        string custId = e.Parameter as string;
        int custIDLookup = Convert.ToInt32(custId);
        lookUp(custIDLookup);
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access data on DetailsPage? Here you are:

```
    public sealed partial class DetailPage : Page
    {
      public DetailPage()
      {
        this.InitializeComponent();
      }

      protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
      {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        Customers customer = (Customers)e.Parameter;

        //Now you can get it from customer object
      }
    }
```